# What is Full form of hFE of a digital multimeter?

Tags: transistors, multimeter, terminology, test

[image: Digital multimeter, downloaded from Web]

In digital multimeter, there is a transistor-check function, and there is a term hFE. I do-not know how-to use-it, however, different Websites **say it is a measurement  transistor's gain ("the ratio of the Ic/Ib")** [such as:  https://www.quora.com/What-does-hFE-mean-on-a-multimeter   ;etc.](https://www.quora.com/What-does-hFE-mean-on-a-multimeter) .

But I want to know, what-is the **full-form (full-NAME) of hFE?**

Comment: Useful search term : h-parameters

Comment: Or just look for "transistor Beta".

Comment: Related: [Why are h-parameters used?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is a mouth-full to say as a full name.
[I found this description here.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100622054502AAhBNdm)

> hFE is an abbreviation, and it stands for "***Hybrid*** parameter **forward** current gain, common **emitter**", and is a measure of the DC gain of a
>   junction transistor.  So on a multimeter, it indicates a mode where
>   the meter can measure (probably crudely), the HFE of a transistor.

**EDIT:** When I talk about transistor gain with other engineer's, we often use the term 'beta', yet in a datasheet 'hFE' is normally what is used by the manufacture based on calibrated equipment for a standalone transistor.
 For some transistors hFE readings may be done at several crucial frequencies as well as DC. 'Beta' is a better term for common-base designs, or just a general statement about DC and/or AC current gain *in a known circuit*.
 As a refinement of the original answer, @carloc mentioned that a 'hFE' spelling refers to a DC signal of relatively large amplitude, while 'hfe' refers to a small signal measured deferentially around some common bias point. No specific thresholds were given, though my original answer refers to 'hFE', the DC gain of the transistor.

Comment: May-be mouthfull... I always try to know the full-forms because the full-names commonly "explain" or "define" ownslfs, or at-least "tell" some thing. Thanks.

Comment: You may wish to add the hFE (capital F and E) is DC large signal measured, while hfe (small f and e) is small signal differential around some bias point.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if I'm understood correctly the question; You want to know the meaning of "F" and "E"?
H is for **H**ybrid (parameter), F meaning **F**orward (current amplification) and E is for common **E**mitter configuration.

Comment: Yes I asked  what is "h", "F", and "E"

Comment: Ok, I'm not mentioned H (added now) but also Sparky256's reply explain it.

Answer (score 4):

In simple terms it runs a small current fron base to emitter and measures how many times greater the resulting collector to emitter current is. This is the DC amplification or DC beta. Besides a crude test to see if the transistor is working it is useful in DC awitching circuits. For AC beta they measure amount of change in collector current resulting from a change in base current.